# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'choices'

Tags: python, django

```
class StatisticsBaseForm(forms.Form):
    type_choice = forms.ChoiceField(_("Type"), choices=settings.STATISTICS_TYPE_CHOICES, default=0)
    period = forms.ChoiceField("Period", max_length=20, choices=settings.PERIODS, default='week')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StatisticsBaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)

    class Meta:
        model = Statistics
        fields = '__all__'
```

The traceback is the following

```
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/django/loanwolf/statistics/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from loanwolf.statistics.views import StatisticsIndexView
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/django/loanwolf/statistics/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from loanwolf.statistics.forms import StatisticsBaseForm
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/django/loanwolf/statistics/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    class StatisticsBaseForm(forms.Form):
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/django/loanwolf/statistics/forms.py", line 18, in StatisticsBaseForm
    type_choice = forms.ChoiceField(_("Type"), choices=settings.STATISTICS_TYPE_CHOICES, default=0)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'choices'
```

I have this error, but I didn't manage to fix it. How could I go ahead on the error? At the beginning, `StatisticsBaseForm` was a `forms.ModelForm`, and `type_choice` and `period` was in my Statistics model where both were `SmallIntegerfield`. In that specific context, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
type_choice = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Type"), choices=settings.STATISTICS_TYPE_CHOICES, initial=0)
period = forms.ChoiceField(label="Period", choices=settings.PERIODS, initial='week')
```